# Consecutive image layout in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm working on a website that has an interface with a series of 12 ASP.NET ImageButton controls - six on top, six on the bottom. These render as `<input type="image" />` HTML elements. They are meant to be laid out left to right, as the screen shot below shows.

[image: The 12 image icons are laid out left to right, one row on top of another.]

The markup correctly laid out the icons in Firefox, IE and Chrome until recently. Recently a customer noticed that in Chrome the images are not laid out horizontally but instead one on top of another, as the screen shot below illustrates.

[image: The 12 image icons are laid out one on top of another in Chrome.]

You can see the markup in action at http://fuzzylogicinc.net/demos/snippet.html. If you view it using IE or Firefox the buttons are laid out correctly, left to right. If you view it in latest version of Chrome the buttons are laid out top to bottom.

The markup is the same, obviously, and there is minimal styling in the above demo/snippet. What do I need to do to get it working in Chrome?

Here is the (abbreviated) markup for the image buttons. There is no additional styling that is applied.

```
<input type="image" name="..." id="..." title="General Invoice" src="..." style="height:20px;border-width:0px;" />

<input type="image" name="..." id="..." title="General Invoice" src="..." style="height:20px;border-width:0px;" />

<input type="image" name="..." id="..." title="General Invoice" src="..." style="height:20px;border-width:0px;" />

...

<br />

<input type="image" name="..." id="..." title="General Invoice" src="..." style="height:20px;border-width:0px;" />

<input type="image" name="..." id="..." title="General Invoice" src="..." style="height:20px;border-width:0px;" />

<input type="image" name="..." id="..." title="General Invoice" src="..." style="height:20px;border-width:0px;" />

...
```

Thanks!

Comment: ur td width is causing the issue - its 100% .. make it - style="white-space: nowrap;" for the button row ( 1st row)

Comment: @user1428716 yep exactly - u should put that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your td width is causing the issue  its 100% .. make it - style="white-space: nowrap;" for the button row ( 1st row)

```
 <tbody><tr><td>..<td>..
 <td  style="white-space: nowrap;">
 <input type="submit" name="ctl00$Content01$btnGotoOrderNumber" value="Go" .....
```

Comment: That does the trick, thanks a million! Do you have any idea why the markup prior to the fix worked earlier? We had tested with Chrome several months ago without issue.

Comment: @ScottMitchell Chromium bug - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118309